# vhost config to disable caching of all files

Tags: regex, apache, virtualhost

Is this syntax correct for my vhost? I'm not sure that is the correct regex for **all** files.

```
<filesMatch "\.*">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct expression to match all files is

```
<filesMatch ".*">
```

Or

```
<filesMatch "^.*$">
```

In the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#filesmatch), it is written:

> The `<FilesMatch>` directive limits the scope of the enclosed directives
>   by filename, just as the `<Files>` directive does. **However, it accepts a
>   regular expression**.

The `\.*` regex accepts `......`-like strings because the `.` is escaped in the pattern.

Just the example (`<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">`) is misleading, as it only matches files that end in `.gif` or `.jpg`, or `png`, or `jpeg`.